# creating species discovery curve using mark recapture data

Tags: r

I am working in `R` and am looking to create a cumulative discovery curve for bat ringing data. We do two visits a year and what we are really interested in is whether we need to do two visits or whether we can get away with just doing one. For this, we wanted to graph the cumulative recapture/discovery rate for visit one and two and see whether these are vastly different. This way we can see over time whether even with one visits we can still record the majority of bats using the caves.

I have graphed the cumulative capture rates over time (total of one year added to the total of the next) but I am trying to just look at the cumulative recapture rate of the unique individuals over time.

A subsample of the data is shown below. We have our field season(year), unique ringing code for each bat and whether it was visit one or two.

```
             Field.season   Ring_Number       visit_number
    184                 28     m3061                 1           
    185                 28     m4653                 1           
    186                 28     m4653                 1           
    187                 28     m5072                 1           
    188                 28     m5865                 1           
    189                 28     m5930                 1           
    190                 28     m8900                 1           
    191                 28     m8932                 1           
    192                 28     m9010                 1           
    193                 28     m9174                 1           
    194                 28     m9179                 1           
    195                 28     m9180                 1           
    196                 28     m9187                 1           
    197                 28     m9188                 1           
    198                 28     m9189                 1           
    199                 28     m9190                 1           
    200                 28     m9191                 1           
    201                 28     m9192                 1           
    202                 28     m9193                 1           
    203                 28     m9194                 1           
    204                 28     m9195                 1           
    205                 28     m9196                 1           
    206                 28     m9197                 1           
    207                 28     m9198                 1           
    208                 28     m9199                 1           
    209                 28     m9199                 1           
    210                 28      x301                 1           
    211                 28      x303                 1           
    212                 28      x322                 1           
    213                 28      x332                 1           
    214                 28     m5910                 1           
    215                 28     m7023                 1           
    216                 28     m8936                 1           
    217                 28      x305                 1           
    218                 28      x307                 1           
    219                 28      x316                 1           
    220                 28      x320                 1           
    221                 28      x329                 1           
    222                 28      x330                 1           
    223                 28      x341                 1           
    224                 28      x407                 1           
    225                 28      x408                 1           
    226                 28      x409                 1          
    227                 28      x410                 1          
    228                 28      x411                 1          
    229                 28      x412                 1           
    230                 28      x413                 1           
    231                 28      x414                 1           
    232                 28      x415                 1           
    233                 28      x416                 1           
    234                 28      x417                 1           
    235                 28      x418                 1           
    236                 28      x419                 1           
    237                 28      x421                 1           
    238                 28      x422                 1           
    239                 28      x423                 1           
    240                 28      x424                 1           
    241                 28      x425                 1           
    242                 28      x426                 1           
    243                 28      x427                 1           
    244                 28      x428                 1           
    245                 28      x429                 1           
    246                 28      x430                 1           
    247                 28      x431                 1           
    248                 28      x432                 1           
    249                 28      x434                 1           
    250                 28      x450                 1           
    251                 28      x496                 1           
    252                 28      x497                 1           
    253                 28      x499                 1           
    254                 28     m5088                 1           
    255                 28     m5910                 1           
    256                 28     m5924                 1           
    257                 28     m5931                 1           
    258                 28     m5935                 1           
    259                 28     m5953                 1           
    260                 28     m5992                 1           
    261                 28     m8880                 1           
    262                 28     m8881                 1           
    263                 28      x302                 1           
    264                 28      x305                 1           
    265                 28      x311                 1           
    266                 28      x311                 1           
    267                 28      x315                 1           
    268                 28      x333                 1           
    269                 28      x338                 1           
    270                 28      x341                 1           
    271                 28      x408                 1           
    272                 28      x410                 1           
    273                 28      x412                 1          
    274                 28      x414                 1           
    275                 28      x415                 1           
    276                 28      x416                 1           
    277                 28      x418                 1           
    278                 28      x426                 1           
    279                 28      x430                 1           
    280                 28      x434                 1           
    281                 28      x435                 1           
    282                 28      x436                 1           
    283                 28      x437                 1           
    284                 28      x438                 1           
    285                 28      x439                 1           
    286                 28      x440                 1           
    287                 28      x441                 1           
    288                 28      x442                 1           
    289                 28      x443                 1           
    290                 28      x444                 1           
    291                 28      x445                 1           
    292                 28      x447                 1           
    293                 28      x448                 1           
    294                 28      x497                 1           
    295                 28      x500                 1           
    296                 28     m3504                 2           
    297                 28     m4584                 2           
    298                 28     m5059                 2           
    299                 28     m5910                 2           
    300                 28     m5953                 2           
    301                 28     m7023                 2           
    302                 28     m8909                 2           
    303                 28     m8936                 2           
    304                 28      x304                 2           
    305                 28      x327                 2           
    306                 28      x333                 2           
    307                 28      x338                 2           
    308                 28      x341                 2           
    309                 28      x351                 2           
    310                 28      x352                 2           
    311                 28      x353                 2           
    312                 28      x354                 2           
    313                 28      x355                 2           
    314                 28      x356                 2           
    315                 28      x357                 2           
    316                 28      x358                 2           
    317                 28      x408                 2           
    318                 28      x412                 2           
    319                 28      x418                 2           
    320                 28      x426                 2           
    321                 28      x429                 2           
    322                 28      x431                 2           
    323                 28      x432                 2           
    324                 28      x438                 2           
    325                 28      x439                 2           
    326                 28      x448                 2           
    327                 28      x449                 2           
    328                 28      x450                 2           
    329                 28      x497                 2           
    330                 28      x498                 2           
    331                 28      x500                 2           
    339                 29     m4885                 1           
    340                 29     m6912                 1           
    341                 29     m8993                 1           
    342                 29     m9019                 1           
    343                 29     m9178                 1           
    344                 29      x405                 1           
    345                 29      x421                 1           
    346                 29     m3504                 1           
    347                 29     m5103                 1           
    348                 29     m5954                 1           
    349                 29     m7083                 1           
    350                 29     m8874                 1           
    351                 29     m8935                 1           
    352                 29     m8938                 1           
    353                 29     m8995                 1           
    354                 29     m9582                 1          
    355                 29      x358                 1           
    356                 29      x410                 1           
    357                 29      x414                 1           
    358                 29      x426                 1           
    359                 29      x438                 1           
    360                 29      x451                 1           
    361                 29      x452                 1           
    362                 29      x454                 1           
    363                 29      x455                 1           
    364                 29      x456                 1           
    365                 29      x457                 1           
    366                 29      x458                 1           
    367                 29      x459                 1           
    368                 29      x460                 1           
    369                 29      x461                 1           
    370                 29      x462                 1           
    371                 29      x463                 1           
    372                 29      x464                 1           
    373                 29      x465                 1           
    374                 29      x466                 1           
    375                 29      x467                 1           
    376                 29      x468                 1           
    377                 29      x469                 1           
    378                 29      x470                 1           
    379                 29      x471                 1           
    380                 29      x472                 1           
    381                 29      x473                 1           
    382                 29      x474                 1           
    383                 29      x475                 1           
    384                 29      x476                 1           
    385                 29     m5210                 1           
    386                 29     m5920                 1           
    387                 29     m5931                 1           
    388                 29     m5935                 1           
    389                 29     m8936                 1           
    390                 29     m9175                 1           
    391                 29     m9200                 1           
    392                 29      x304                 1           
    393                 29      x305                 1           
    394                 29      x327                 1           
    395                 29      x345                 1           
    396                 29      x351                 1           
    397                 29      x353                 1           
    398                 29      x354                 1           
    399                 29      x359                 1           
    400                 29      x360                 1           
    401                 29      x362                 1           
    402                 29      x363                 1           
    403                 29      x364                 1           
    404                 29      x365                 1           
    405                 29      x366                 1           
    406                 29      x367                 1           
    407                 29      x368                 1           
    408                 29      x369                 1           
    409                 29      x371                 1           
    410                 29      x372                 1           
    411                 29      x373                 1           
    412                 29      x374                 1           
    413                 29      x375                 1           
    414                 29      x376                 1           
    415                 29      x377                 1           
    416                 29      x378                 1           
    417                 29      x379                 1           
    418                 29      x380                 1           
    419                 29      x381                 1           
    420                 29      x382                 1           
    421                 29      x383                 1           
    422                 29      x384                 1           
    423                 29      x385                 1           
    424                 29      x386                 1           
    425                 29      x386                 1           
    426                 29      x387                 1           
    427                 29      x389                 1           
    428                 29      x390                 1           
    429                 29      x391                 1           
    430                 29      x392                 1           
    431                 29      x393                 1           
    432                 29      x394                 1           
    433                 29      x395                 1           
    434                 29      x396                 1           
    435                 29      x397                 1           
    436                 29      x398                 1           
    437                 29      x399                 1           
    438                 29      x400                 1           
    439                 29      x409                 1           
    440                 29      x417                 1
```

any help would greatly be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
to make an example of what I have been trying but dont know if it is the correct code at all includes:

```
df1 <- df[which(df$visit_number == 1), ]
df2 <- df[which(df$visit_number == 2), ]

library(asnipe)
individuals1 <- data.frame(D = df1$Ring_Number, GROUP = df1$Field.season)
gbi1 <- get_group_by_individual(individuals1, data_format = "individuals")

library(vegan)
sp1 <- specaccum(gbi1)
sp2 <- specaccum(gbi1, "random")
sp2
summary(sp2)
plot(sp1, ci.type="poly", col="blue", lwd=2, ci.lty=0, ci.col="lightblue")
boxplot(sp2, col="yellow", add=TRUE, pch="+")
## Fit Lomolino model to the exact accumulation
mod1 <- fitspecaccum(sp1, "lomolino")
coef(mod1)
fitted(mod1)
plot(sp1)
## Add Lomolino model using argument 'add'
plot(mod1, add = TRUE, col=2, lwd=2)
## Fit Arrhenius models to all random accumulations
mods <- fitspecaccum(sp2, "arrh")
plot(mods, col="hotpink")
boxplot(sp2, col = "yellow", border = "blue", lty=1, cex=0.3, add= TRUE)
## Use nls() methods to the list of models
sapply(mods$models, AIC)

#this was then done for df2 (gbi2) for comparison.
```

But I am not sure it is doing exactly what I am thinking it is doing.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, you want to find out how many new ring numbers you discover in the second visit compared to the first? Does it reset after a year (i.e. all ring numbers are "new" again in year 2)?

Comment: hello @erocoar, yes that is correct and how that changes in relation to time. so, for example, a ring could have been found on the 2nd visit of year 1 however if we didn't do a second visit it could have been recorded on the 1st visit of year 2 and so would still be in our database. no, I don't think it would reset but rather be a cumulative process over time. Does that make sense? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so how about this:

- you split the rings into separate vectors for each Season/Visit combination

...

```
ring_per_visit <- split(df$Ring, list(df$Number, df$Field.season))
```

- you loop over it, for each one calculating the set difference compared to a vector containing all previously discovered rings/species (i.e., you retain only the ones that are newly discovered during that visit)
- you normalize this by how many rings were looked at in total during the visit

... (the result is in reverse)

```
discoveries <- sapply(rev(seq_along(ring_per_visit)), function(x) {
    if (x != 1) {
      length(unique(unlist(setdiff(
        ring_per_visit[[x]], 
        unlist(ring_per_visit[seq(x - 1)])
        )
        ))) / length(ring_per_visit[[x]])
    } else {
    length(unique(ring_per_visit[[x]])) / length(ring_per_visit[[x]])
    }
  }
)
```

Then you can plot it, e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(
    x = factor(c("Y1V1", "Y1V2", "Y2V1", "Y2V2")), 
    y = rev(discoveries),
    group = 1
  )) +
  ylim(0, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. From looking at the graph though if only the new ones are retained as well as the old ones and so are cumulative over time, shouldn't Y2V! be greater than Y1V1? and would it be possible to have two separate lines for each visit to make easy comparisons?